# Creating a 4x2 2D coordinate system centered around (0,0)?

Tags: opengl, coordinates

I am having trouble setting a orthographical projection matrix of dimensions 4x2 with (0,0) being in the center, (-2, -1) being at the bottom left corner, and (2, 1) being at the top right corner.

I use `glutInitWindowSize(600, 300);` to initialize the window size.
In my reshape function, I use `glViewport(0, 0, w, h);` to set the viewport.
Also in my reshape function, I use `gluOrtho2D(-(float)w/h, (float)w/h, -2.0, 2.0);` to set the ortho.

However, when I move my mouse around to see the world coordinates, the bottom left corner is (-1, -1) and the top right corner is (1, 1). Is there something I am doing wrong here? I am assuming since I am setting bottom and top to -2 and 2 respectively in the gluOrtho2D call, it should give me the right coordinates.

Please help me out if you see anything that might be wrong.

Here is my code so far, please ignore the arm variables and drawing functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#if 0 /*unix*/
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#if 1 /*apple */
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <OPENGL/gl.h>
#include <OPENGL/glext.h>
#endif

#if 0 /*windows*/
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <glut.h>
#endif

int GW, GH;
bool animfore, animupper;
float foreangle, upperangle;

using namespace std;

void drawShoulder();
void drawUpper();
void drawFore();

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //draw shoulder
    glPushMatrix();
        drawShoulder();
        //draw upper arm
        glPushMatrix();
            drawUpper();
            //draw forearm
            glPushMatrix();
                drawFore();
            glPopMatrix();
        glPopMatrix();
    glPopMatrix();

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void drawShoulder() {
    //cout << "Enters" << endl;

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f((float)30/255, (float)0/255, (float)30/255);
        glVertex2f(-2.0, -0.4);
        glVertex2f(-2.0, -1.0);
        glVertex2f(-1.0, -1.0);
        glVertex2f(-1.0, -0.4);
    glEnd();
}

void drawUpper() {

}

void drawFore() {

}

void reshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h) {
    GW = w;
    GW = h;
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-(float)w/h, (float)w/h, -1.0, 1.0);
    cout << "Enters" << endl;
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    switch(key) {
        case 'q' : case 'Q' :
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
    }
}

//control arm animations
void idle() {
    if(animupper) {

    }
    if(animfore) {

    }
}
float p2w_x(int gx) {
    return (float)2.*GW/(GW*GH-GH)*gx-(float)GW/GH;
}

float p2w_y(int gy) {
    int py = GH-1-gy;
    return (float)2./(GH-1.)*py-1;
}

void mouseMove(int x, int y) {
    cout << "(" << p2w_x(x) << "," << p2w_y(y) << ")" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // global variable intializations
    GW = 600;
    GH = 300;
    animfore, animupper = true;

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);

    // initialization
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 300);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Robot Arm");
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    // callback functions
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutMotionFunc(mouseMove);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION )` before you make your ortho call and then set it back to GL_MODELVIEW when you do your transformations.